# How to keep the original text formatting in TextField django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

How to keep the original text formatting (e.g. new lines, bold text) in TextField django admin.

For example, I want to place text on two lines. But in html code I see only one line **"Line1 Line2"**

I found solution --- usage of html tags, but it's not suitable for me.

**How to keep the original text formatting without html tags in django?**
Any design advises?

**UPD 1**
I added "< pre >" tag, and how can I remove scroll at the end?
[image]

**mycode.html**

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container" style="margin-top: 20px">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <h1>{{vacancy}}</h1>
            <h2>{{vacancy.salary}}</h2>
            <h3><a href="{% url 'company_detail' pk=vacancy.company_key.pk %}">{{vacancy.company_key.name}}</a></h3>
            <p>{{vacancy.city}}</p>
            <p><pre>{{vacancy.text| safe}}</pre></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Showing the result inside a `<pre></pre>` tag might be a solution :)

Comment: @PayamMohammadi how can I remove scroll at the end? (see image)

Comment: Use [css](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_overflow.asp). `overflow: visible`.